# Find path between nodes in flat array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I Have a flat array of connections which represent the connection of nodes in a tree.

```js
const connections = [
  {
    id: "first",
    source: "root",
    target: "A_fbb03",
  },
  {
    source: "A_fbb03",
    target: "W_c0f6f",
    id: "A_fbb03_W_c0f6f",
  },
  {
    source: "A_fbb03",
    target: "W_4c2dd",
    id: "A_fbb03_W_4c2dd",
  },
  {
    id: "A_fbb03_W_1f0ac",
    source: "A_fbb03",
    target: "W_1f0ac",
  },
  {
    id: "W_c0f6f_S_007f5",
    source: "W_c0f6f",
    target: "S_007f5",
  },
];
```

When adding a new connection between nodes, I want to check if this connection creating a loop, meaning that the target node has a path to the source node.

I came up with a function:

```js
function isLoopConnection = (newConnection, connections) => {
  const theSource = newConnection.source
  let theTarget = newConnection.target
  let isLoop = false

 
  for (let i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
    const nextConnection = connections.filter(item => item.source === theTarget)
    if (nextConnection.length) {
      for (const nc of nextConnection) {
        if (nc.target === theSource) {
          isLoop = true
          break
        } else {
          theTarget = nc.target
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return isLoop
}
```

Obviously this is not working well in certain cases and feels way too complicated.
For example: when I add a new connection which suppose to create a loop between `S_007f5`
to `A_fbb03` because `A_fbb03` has a path to `S_007f5` through `W_c0f6f`

```
A_fbb03 -> W_c0f6f -> S_007f5 -> A_fbb03
```

```js
{
  id: "S_007f5_A_fbb03",
  source: "S_007f5",
  target: "A_fbb03",
}
```

The function return `false`

Any suggestions how to improve this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and store seen node identifier.

This approach generates an object whit all children of all nodes. To get result, all items are used to check for circular references.

```js
const
    hasLoop = array => {
        const
           children = array.reduce((r, { source, target }) => ((r[source] ??= []).push(target), r), {}),
           check = (node, seen = new Set) => {
               if (seen.has(node)) return true;
               seen.add(node);
               return (children[node] || []).some(node => check(node, seen));
           };

        return array.some(({ source }) => check(source));
    },
    connections = [{ source: "root", target: "A_fbb03" }, { source: "A_fbb03", target: "W_c0f6f" }, { source: "A_fbb03", target: "W_4c2dd" }, { source: "A_fbb03", target: "W_1f0ac" }, { source: "W_c0f6f", target: "S_007f5" }, { source: "S_007f5", target: "A_fbb03" }];


console.log(hasLoop(connections.slice(0, -1))); // false
console.log(hasLoop(connections));              //  true
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that the new connection doesn't exist yet in the connections array during this check, this is why my function accept newConnection as argument. I Guess I can add it to connections at the beginning of your solution.